# Does the Java compiler know that t.getClass() always returns Class<T>? Can it be made aware of method contracts?

Tags: java, generics, compilation

Do I understand correctly that the Java compiler is unaware of the fact that `t.getClass()` always returns `Class<T>`?

```java
    public ObjectField(T object, FieldExtractor<T> fieldExtractor) {
        this.object = object;
        this.field = fieldExtractor.extract(object.getClass());
    }
```

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FieldExtractor<T> {
    Field extract(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception;
}
```

For `object.getClass()`:

```
Required type:
Class
<T>
Provided:
Class
<capture of ? extends Object>
```

I know that a compiler can't execute any code and have to make only those assumptions that can be made safely at compile time. However, can a compiler ever be made aware of some iron-clad contracts that methods provide (so that it knows some things even without executing a method)? Do such "smart" compilers theoretically possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The [`Object#getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) method is defined to return "_Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called_", so that's what the compiler sees.

Comment: @Slaw is there something we can do about it?

Comment: I tried using `? super T` and `? extends T` in various places and none of it would compile. Only thing I can think of right now is to change the parameter type of `extract` from `Class<T>` to just `T`, then let the implementation handle getting the class of the object. But I don't know if that would work for you.

Comment: "the fact that `t.getClass()` always returns `Class<T>`" That's not true. For example, if we have `Animal animal = new Dog;`, then according to your claim `animal.getClass()` should always return `Class<Animal>`, but `animal.getClass()` actually returns `Dog.class`, which has type `Class<Dog>`, and does not have type `Class<Animal>` (`Class<Dog>` is not a subtype of `Class<Animal>`, nor vice versa, even though `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`).